# Can narrower inside of gate valve reduce pressure by losses?

Tags: plumbing

I notice a ppr 3/4" gate valve has narrower inside compared to a 3/4" bronze gate valve which has wider inside. I guess the pressure inside the bronze gate is stronger? I wonder why would they make the ppr gate valve smaller inside.

[image]

The white one has the following inside it

[image]!

Comment: The plastic valve is a globe valve and the brass valve is a gate valve. You are discussing 2 different valve types.

Answer (score 2):

The bronze valve will offer a lower pressure drop to the flow of water as the path has fewer changes of direction or changes in diameter.

The diagram for the plastic valve shows a 90 degree change in direction, then the flow is constricted through an orifice, then a further 90 degree change of direction.

Using the plastic valve when the flow rate and therefore velocity is low won’t be too serious like a low flow drip feed watering system but if the flow rate needs to be higher, shower or filling a bath then the losses may well cause an issue.